# C generating random values for int variables

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default values of int when not initialized in c. why do i get different outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609041/default-values-of-int-when-not-initialized-in-c-why-do-i-get-different-outputs)

Beginner so be lil soft..am compiling a simple code below, I am not assigning any value to my variables but C program generates some random values, why is it so?(Only 2nd variable generates random integers)

So where these values came from?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(void) {
    int var1;
    int var2;

    printf("Var1 is %d and Var2 is %d.", var1, var2);
    return 0; //Book says I should use this for getting an output but my compiler anyways compile and return me values whether I use it or not
}

//Output 1st compiled: var1 = 19125, var2 = 8983
//Output 2nd compiled: var1 = 19125, var2 = 9207
//Output 2nd compiled: var1 = 19125, var2 = 9127
```

Comment: What you have here is *not* random; it is by definition of the C standard (3.19.2) **indeterminate**. If you want a pseudo-random number, use rand(). If you want a *real* pseudo-random number, is a blessed-crypto-library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *C* program is compiled to some executable program. Notice that if you compile on Linux using `gcc -Wall`, you'll get warnings about uninitialized variables.

The `var1` and `var2` variables get compiled into using some stack slots, or some registers. These contain some apparently random number, which your program prints. (that number is not really random, it is just unpredictable garbage).

The *C* language does not mandate the implicit initialization of variables (in contrast with e.g. Java).

In practice, in *C* I strongly suggest to **always explicitly initialize local variables** (often, the compiler may be smart enough to even avoid emitting useless initialization).

What you observe is called [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You'll probably observe a different output for `var1` if you compiled with a different compiler, or with different optimization flags, or with a different environment (probably typing `export SOMEVAR=something` before running again your program could change the output for `var1`, or running your program with a lot of program arguments, etc...).

You could (on Linux) compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S` and add various optimization flags (e.g. `-O1` or `-O2` ...) your source code `yoursource.c` and look inside the generated `yoursource.s` assembler code with some editor.

Answer (score 2):

In C, when you declare variables, that reserves some space for them on the stack. The stack is how C keeps track of which arguments are passed to which function, where variables are stored if you declare them statically within function, where return values are stored, and so on. Each time you call a function, it pushes values on the stack; that is, it writes those values to the next available space on the stack, and updates the stack pointer to account for this. When a function returns, it decrements the stack pointer, to point to where it pointed in the previous function call.

If you declare a variable, but you don't initialize it, you simply get whatever value was in there before. If another function has been called, you may get the arguments passed in to that function; or you might get the return address for the function you are returning to.

In the case that you present, you are showing the `main()` function, with no other functions called. However, in the process of loading your program, the dynamic linker has probably called several functions within your process space. So the values that you are seeing are probably left over from that.

You cannot depend on what these values are, however. They could be anything; they could be initialized to 0, they could be random data, they could be any sort of internal data.

Answer (score 1):

The content of var1 and var2 are undefined. Thus, they can contain any valid value (depending on many external factors).

It is pure luck that only the second var seams to be random. Try it on another day, after a reboot or after launching a few other programms and I bet the first var will have changed.

Comment: Than why does `var1` value remains constant and `var2` value changes?

Comment: @HelloWorld there is nothing that specifies that `var1` _must_ remain constant - it just so happened that way for you.  You shouldn't rely on this behaviour - that's what it means for the behaviour to be undefined.

Comment: @HelloWorld: Different memory map, different execution paths - different garbage. No one can say for sure.

Comment: @BrianL so I shouldn't care about this, does this thing affect my code in any way?

Comment: @HelloWorld: You should initialize your variables to something usefull before using them.

Comment: @HelloWorld the thing you're supposed to do is write your program so that the behaviour is defined (I guess defining behaviour is one way to think about programming!)  As Burkhard says, the C language requires you to initialize the variables before using them (other languages might make all integers zero by default).

Answer (score 0):

It's called local variables . Any local variables have `auto` storage specifier and these are located on stack in C.

Since you havn't initilaized these varaibles , so it will take any value called `garbage value` or `indeterminate value` (Language standard doesn't imposes any requirements that it must have specific value ) so you are getting any random value.

It's purely coincedence that you are getting same value for `var1` but not for `var2`.
But on any other system it might give different values or even on your system may after sometime.
So,Using uninitialized variables is `undefined behaviour`

Answer (score 0):

In C,

If the variables are declared as Global or static, then they are automatically initialised to zero. But, if they are declared as local , then the values for those variables are indeterminate i.e .., depends on the compiler. (Some garbage value)